# Visual Studio is tweaking sizes of menu items

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm writing a simple WinForms program in C# with Visual Studio 2015, and running into a weird little - not problem, exactly, but unexplained phenomenon. I've added a menu bar and toolbar with standard items, and am filling in actions for some of them. As I do so, I notice Visual Studio keeps tweaking the sizes of various items e.g.

```
this.aboutToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 22);
```

the 152 used to be 122, and I didn't change the size or layout of anything, didn't make any design changes at all. I'm not noticing any visible difference, and maybe it's something I don't need to worry about, but I figure I better check just in case it is.

Anyone know what exactly is going on here and why?

Comment: Have you changed the DPI of your monitor recently?

Comment: Have you been adding ShortcutKeys to the menu items that have changed?  That would make the menus wider...

Comment: @adv12 No to both. I've only been adding actions for menu items. And not even for the ones that changed width.

Comment: `ToolStripMenuItem` is auto-size by default. that size doesn't have any impact on your run-time as long as you keep it auto-sized.